# How do you set cookies with Dryscrape?

Tags: cookies, webkit, dryscrape

I want to set cookies, but they disappear.

```
import dryscrape
dryscrape.start_xvfb()
session = dryscrape.Session()
session.set_cookie('a=b')
session.cookies() # returns []
```

It looks like `session.set_cookie` is calling `session.conn.issue_command("SetCookie", cookie)` where session.conn is a `webkit_server.ServerConnection`. I tried all kinds of string formats such as

```
session.set_cookie('Cookie: a=b')
```

but I've never gotten a cookie to stick around.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use a complete cookie string, something along the lines of

```
session.set_cookie(
    u'a=b; expires=Thu, 15-Mar-2018 18:37:51 GMT; '
    'domain=.whatever.com; path=/')
```